# What is the command to log out of Google App Engine SDK?

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

I completed version 1 of my Google App Engine site but when deploying it I used a different set of credentials from the ones I registered the Google App Engine app ID under. Accordingly the GAE SDK can't upload my app when I give the command:

```
mvn appengine:update
```

...because it remembers the wrong credentials and never asks me for the correct ones. How do I log out of the old credentials and log in with the new ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're on Windows : Go in your "C:/Users/whicheverUserIsYou". You should find a file called ".appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java".

If you're on Linux : the file is in fact "~/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java"

This is the file containing your credentials. Delete/Rename it, maven will ask for your credentials again.

Answer (score 1):

if u mean google cloud sdk then the command is (gcloud auth revoke [your id])